# Hide Bottom Tab Navigator when inside Stack with @ react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to hide my bottom tab navigator using @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs when entering the app. Basically, I only want it visible on either of the home screens, otherwise I don't want to see it. I think my error my stem from my formatting of my functions, but I am unsure. Below is my current code that has the bottom tab navigator present at almost all times.

Also, here is also the example I tried to follow off of from React's website https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const MainTab = createStackNavigator();
const MainTabStack = createStackNavigator();
const SecondTabStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function MainTabScreen ({navigation}) {  //MainTabScreen is also the name of the file
  return (

<Tab.Navigator 
  activeColor = '#fff'
  inactiveColor = '#fff'
  barStyle = {{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}

  screenOptions ={{
      headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:"#fff"         
        },
        gestureEnabled: false,
        headTintColor: '#fff', 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          shadowColor: '#fff',
        },  
    }}
    >

    <Tab.Screen 
      name = " " 
      component={MainTabStackScreen} 
      options= {{

  
        tabBarLabel: 'Label',
        tabBarColor: '#009387',

        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) =>(
          <Icon name = "ios-home" color={color} size = {height*0.027}/>
          ),

        }}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        name = "  "
        component = { SecondTabStackScreen }
        options = {{
          tabBarLabel: 'Label2',
          tabBarColor: '#fff',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) =>(
            <Icon name = "ios-home" color = {color} size = {height*0.027}/>

            ),
        }}
      />
  </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    //)
  }

export default MainTabScreen ;


  function MainTabStackScreen ({navigation}) {
  return(
  
    <MainTabStack.Navigator
      screenOptions ={{
      headerStyle:{
          backgroundColor:"#fff"         
        },
        gestureEnabled: false,
        headTintColor: '#fff', 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          shadowColor: '#fff',
        }
      }}>

      <MainTabStack.Screen name = "PreHomeScreen" component={PreHomeScreen} //App won't load when replaced with MainTabScreen like in example
      options= {{
        title: '',
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button name = "ios-menu" size={25} backgroundColor= "#fff" onPress={ () => navigation.openDrawer()}> </Icon.Button>
          ) 

      }}/>

      <MainTabStack.Screen 
        name = "Home" 
        component={HomeScreen} 
        options= {{
          title: '',
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Icon.Button name = "md-arrow-back" size={25} backgroundColor= "#009387" onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('PreHomeScreen')}> </Icon.Button>
          ),         
      }}/>

      ...

      </MainTabStack.Navigator>
```